# PHP Regex get the second grouped match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have the following example.

regex:

```
'/test=([0-9]*).*?marker/'
```

testing string:

```
test=1234 test=5678 unknown marker
```

the matched group returns:

```
1234
```

how do I modify the regex to return `5678`, the closest value to the marker?

thanks

edit: I have updated the example. sorry for the confusion. where unknown can be anything

Comment: I have now been using RegexBuddy for all my regex, very helpful;
http://www.regexbuddy.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any of these 2 regex will work:

```
$s = 'test=1234 test=5678 unknown marker'; // input
if (preg_match('/test=(\d+)(?!.*?test=\d+)/', $s, $arr)) var_dump($arr[1]);
// OR
if (preg_match('/test=(\d+)\D*marker/', $s, $arr)) var_dump($arr[1]);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
string(4) "5678"
string(4) "5678"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'test=1234 test=5678 marker';
preg_match('/test=(\d+)\smarker/', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; //=> 5678
```

Comment: thanks, that works. what if the example is like this: test=1234 test=5678 unknown marker.